# React/typescript doesn't recognize component when passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a generic functional component where the props of this components consists of additional components that should be rendered. Typically, a better solution would be to pass these as children instead, but it doesn't really work for this specific use case.

Anyways, the relevant pro looks like this:

```
interface Props<T> {
  ..
  columnDefinitions: {
    [property in keyof T]: {
      title: string;
      Component: (props: { rowIndex: number }) => JSX.Element;
    };
  };
}
```

Since I'm iterating over the keys of T, specific components will be referenced as:
`columnDefinitions[columnName].Component`. This is what I want to render. Ideally, I would like to render it with:
 `<columnDefinitions[columnName].Component rowIndex={rowIndex} />`
However, this will not compile, because typescript does not recognize this as a valid component. What I tried to do instead was the following:

```
const { Component } = columnDefinitions[columnName];
return <Component rowIndex={rowIndex} />
```

This actually compiles and renders, but has some very problematic side effects - because of the `const` declaration, the component gets remounted on each render. Among other things, this means that if the component is an input it will lose focus each time a letter is typed into it.

A third solution I tried was to render it as `{columnDefinitions[columnName].Component({ rowIndex })}`. Again, this compiles and renders. The problem is that it is no longer a functional component! Because I'm invoking it directly with the rowIndex prop, it's actually just a JSX element. This works in most cases, but not if the component is stateful, which it is in some cases.

How do I solve this? Given the difficulty I'm having and the lack of resources online addressing it, I'm beginning to suspect this whole thing is an anti-pattern. Should you avoid passing FC's as props? Again, rendering it has children doesn't work that well in this case, because the wrapping component needs to keep track of various info about the children.

To give more context of the problem, here's the relevant code of the main component. It currently contains an ugly work-around where stateful components are remounted on each render, and other components rendered as plain JSX:

```
interface Props<T> {
  emptyMessage: string;
  onAddRow: () => void;
  onDeleteRow: (rowIndex: number) => void;
  data: T[];
  addRowText?: string;
  disabled: boolean;
  deleteRowText?: string;
  columnOrder: (keyof T)[];
  columnDefinitions: {
    [property in keyof T]: {
      title: string;
      isStateful?: boolean;
      Component: (props: { rowIndex: number }) => JSX.Element;
    };
  };
}
export function DynamicInputTable<T extends object>(props: Props<T>) {
  const {
    columnDefinitions,
    onAddRow,
    onDeleteRow,
    columnOrder,
    data,

  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <section>
          <header>
            {columnOrder.map((columnName) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={"header-" + (columnName as string)}
                  className="col table-header"
                >
                  {columnDefinitions[columnName].title}
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <div className="col table-header"></div>
          </header>
          {data.map((_, rowIndex) => {
            return (
              <div key={rowIndex}>
                {columnOrder.map((columnName) => {
                  if (columnDefinitions[columnName].isStateful) {
                    const { Component } = columnDefinitions[columnName];
                    return (
                      <div key={columnName as string} className="col table-row">
                        <Component rowIndex={rowIndex} />
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <div key={columnName as string} className="col table-row">
                        {columnDefinitions[columnName].Component({ rowIndex })}
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I render `columnDefinitions[columnName].Component` as a component!?

Comment: I started a little sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-turing-h3bhj?file=/src/App.tsx). Could you try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thank you! Hmm, that's really interesting - it looks like it should have the same issue but I can't reproduce it. I will try to figure out what's going on here. This should be very helpful.